# Washing machine hose backing up and overflowing AFTER septic tank has been emptied

Tags: plumbing, septic, washer, flooding

A few months ago, my washer started overflowing from the pvc pipe. A friend who's very well versed at plumbing cut the PVC pipe, snaked it and there was nothing blocking it.  He pulled the cap off the outlet pipe and saw that there was standing water in there. He determined that I needed my septic tank pumped, which I did the next day.  It's been about 3 months and everything has been fine until last nite when I was doing a load of laundry and the EXACT same thing happened. I had a flood of water coming out of the PVC pipe where the washer hose empties into. The septic guy had told me that the the pipe under my deck outside was bowed and that could possibly be why things are hanging up there.  But its' been fine for months!  I'm moving out in 4 weeks and I really don't want to invest any more money in this house. Does it sound like I should try to see exactly how "bowed" that exit pipe is and try to maybe prop it up?  Please help! I'm a woman alone and don't know where to turn.
Thanks for any answers!

Comment: It sounds like you tank is full again..... How often do you do laundry....

Comment: Your leach field may be blocked, so that your tank never empties, or only empties slowly.

Comment: I only do laundry once per week and it's just me.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  Someone else told me that the leach field might be blocked. So I'm just going to try to bear with it for another four weeks until I move out of here.